# Help on MySQL table indexing when GROUP BY is used in a query

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

Thank you for your attention.

There are two INNODB tables:

Table **authors**

```
id        INT
nickname  VARCHAR(50) 
status    ENUM('active', 'blocked')
about     TEXT
```

Table **books**

```
author_id  INT
title      VARCHAR(150)
```

I'm running a query against these tables, to get each author and a count of books he has:

```
SELECT a. * , COUNT( b.id ) AS book_count
FROM authors AS a, books AS b
WHERE a.status != 'blocked'
AND b.author_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY a.nickname
```

This query is very slow (takes about 6 seconds to execute). I have an index on `books.author_id` and it works perfectly, but I do not know how to create an index on `authors` table, so that this query could use it.

Here is how current EXPLAIN looks:

```
id   select_type   table    type    possible_keys               key            key_len   ref     rows    Extra
1    SIMPLE        a        ALL     PRIMARY,id_status_nickname  NULL           NULL      NULL    3305    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1    SIMPLE        b        ref     key_author_id               key_author_id  5         a.id    2       Using where; Using index
```

I've looked at [MySQL manual on optimizing queries with group by](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html), but could not figure out how I  can apply it on my query.

I'll appreciate any help and hints on this - what must be the index structure, so that MySQL could use it?

## Edit

I have tried:

```
(id, status, nickname)
(status, nickname)
```

Both resulted in the same situation.

Comment: Basic rule of thumb for indexing is that any field you using in a join and/or where clause should be indexed. For your query, that'd mean a.id, b.author_id, and a.status all should be indexed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the id_status_nickname is a composite index (id,status,nickname). In your query you filter the rows by saying a.status != blocked. This has following issues:

1. You dont have an index that can be used for this. (id,status,nickname) cannot be used because status is not the prefix of that index
2. Assuming you have an index on status, it cannot be used when using !=. you have to change that to status='active'
3. Also, status being an enum field with just two values the cardinality will be low. So mysql may endup not using the index at all.

You can try this: create index as (status,id,nickname) and use status='active'. My guess is that since you are using '=' and status is the prefix of the index it should select this index and then use it for group by and then order by.Hope this helps.

UPDATE:
Looks like it is not possible to avoid filesort when the WHERE clause does not have the field used in ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

I would try an index on (status, nickname).  That should get rid of the necessity of "Using filesort".